# Returning a promise from a function that gets a response from the background JS of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, es6-promise

So after the CORB issue of chrome extension i migrated the api calls to background script and used callback from the background script to send response of a JSON.

So I have a doubt regarding the response i receive from callback i want it to return it.

```
async function request (path, apiToken, options) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "request", path:path, apiToken:apiToken, options:options}, (all) => {
    return Promise.resolve(all.json )
  })
}
```

I call request => it goes to background => background return the response => then the request function should return a promise.
I'm stuck on the last step as im unable to return it from inside the callback,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return new Promise, resolve it inside your `sendMessage` callback

```
async function request (path, apiToken, options) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "request", path:path, apiToken:apiToken, options:options}, (all) => {
        resolve(all.json)
      })
}
```

Comment: hey thank you soo much for this. It worked! man i spent so much time on this and now i understand promises .

Comment: @sunilupadhyay we are really proud of you! Keep up the good spirit.